# QGIS "couldn't load plugin 'processing" for my windows 10

Tags: qgis

I installed QGIS version 2.18.16   and after finishing installation i tried starting it but it shows the below comment.

> Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 
>       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GRA_Max' 
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
>           **import**(packageName)
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
>           mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing__init__.py",
>   line 28, in 
>           from processing.tools.dataobjects import *          # NOQA
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
>           mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\dataobjects.py",
>   line 37, in 
>           from processing.algs.gdal.GdalUtils import GdalUtils
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
>           mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py",
>   line 32, in 
>           from osgeo import gdal
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
>           mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py",
>   line 116, in 
>           from gdalconst import *
>         File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
>           mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>         File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalconst.py",
>   line 148, in 
>           GRA_Max = _gdalconst.GRA_Max
>       AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GRA_Max'
>       Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
>       QGIS version: 2.18.9 Las Palmas, 3a16a4e 
>       Python Path:
>       C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
>       C:/Users/my/.qgis2/python
>       C:/Users/my/.qgis2/python/plugins
>       C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
>       C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
>       C:/Users/my/.qgis2//python

Comment: Please spent some time to format your question. I highly doubt anyone will read through this.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem with QGIS3, just *uninstall* python 3.7 and *reinstall* python 3.6
This worked for me perfectly.